# Slick carousel breaking for zoom in and zoom out

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

In iPad if we zoom in and orientation change and again zoom out slick carousel not able to detect the changes and not able to come to in the state declared in the settings and also zoom label not reset.

I have added a slider in [this link](http://nabaraj.github.io/slick/). Please check if there is any solution for that.